# Server 2012 SysPrepped Image Prompts to Approve Eula after Domain Join

Tags: windows, active-directory, sysprep

I am trying to upgrade our base web server image from Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012.

Our cloud vendor allows us to SysPrep an IAAS instance, image it and then restore it.

I have this part all working to a point.

After I restore my sysprepped image, boot it and then domain join it upon the restart after domain join I am being prompted to approve the EULA and pick the language!  Of course during this process the network interface is downed preventing you from performing this over RDP.

I could see this happening on initial boot but after the domain join seems really, really weird.  Trying to figure out how to get it back to a state after domain join that I can RDP into it and finish setup.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the restored image once before joining the domain? And did you license and activate the first instance before running sysprep? I haven't used sysprep on 2012 yet, but I do agree that getting the EULA *after* domain join is a little wonky.

Comment: How does your answer XML look like?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I did validate that a license was in place before sysprep, after first boot and before domain join.

Comment: Are you asking about the unattend.xml?  At first I didn't have one.  I have experimented with one containing hideEula as well as including the KMS default product key.